# `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a `df` of Stock data, with the Stocks name, recent move, expected move (based on my model), and the difference between the actual and expected moves. It looks like this:

```
    Stock   Move    Expected  Diff
0   A       77.9    126.03    -48.13
1   B       -58.1   -34.38    -23.72
2   C       8.33    24.67     -16.34
3   D       -67.33  -54.98    -12.35
4   E       -41.91  -30.49    -11.42
5   F       -36.94  -26.33    -10.61
```

The `df` itself is actually quite big, I've just put 5 rows as an example, but what I'm trying to do is iterate through each row in the `df` and if it meets some requirements, print the row. I'm using `iterrows()` in a manner such as this:

```
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    if df['Move'] < 0:
        if df['Diff'] < 0:
            print(df['Stock'], df['Move'], df['Diff'])
```

This produces 2 problems. The first problem is driving me insane. When I run my script from the beginning and download live data through an API connection I get the following error:

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

coming from the line: `if df['Move'] < 0:` so I got the `dtype` of each column and they are indeed `object`.

So I try to convert to to both `int` / `float` to see if that helps by doing `if float(df['Residual']) < 0:` however it produces this error message:
`TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>` 
so it won't even let me convert the data to the required type and this is my first problem.

So I then decided to save the `df` to a csv file, and load the data that way. For some reason my columns are now 'float64`, which in theory solves the first problem above, but then I get this error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Any help would be really appreciated, cheers

Comment: Don't use `iterrows()`! [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758) of mine provides you with a 10,000 foot level of how to write vectorised performant code with pandas.

Comment: Anyway, to address your problem. You should have used `row['col']` inside the loop, but you used `df['col']` which has no meaning when used inside `if`.

Comment: Even if you insist you want to use `iterrows`, the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476974/4909087) will tell you the variable to access inside the loop needs to be `row`, not `df`.

Comment: Ah perfect thanks mate, I got it from another answer, which was obviously wrong. Thanks again

Comment: Don't forget to downvote the answer that misled you!